# Lerna Monorepo keeping individual git repos as packages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, lerna, monorepo

In lerna, one can initialize git at the root level of the lerna project and inside the `packages` folder, we keep our small individual projects. Now suppose, you want to keep the git histories and commits of those packages isolated from each other. Because why do you wanna mix commit histories of un-related projects.
Considering you're merging already existing two or more projects into a lerna project. Do we have no way but to remove the .git folder from those child packages since it introduces that messy git submodules concept into the picture? What's the cleaner way to enjoy monorepo benefits while keeping the git commit histories and workflows independent from each other for the children packages? Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you figured this out or can share anything you've learned from this?

Answer (score 0):

> Now suppose, you want to keep the git histories and commits of those packages isolated from each other. Because why do you wanna mix commit histories of un-related projects.

Isn't this the entire point of `lerna`? Grouping related packages together because they are related and interdependent? I think you might be going for something like [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) if what you want is separate projects that can have dependencies between themselves.

Comment: The point of lerna (monorepo) is to manage dependencies between interrelated packages and have shared configuration (test, eslint etc) for subpackages. It does the job but the question is how to share sub-packages separately and keep commit history separately while managing dependencies with lerna. It would be convenient to be able to give access to some 3rd party devs just for one sub-package repository not to all.